# Why doesn't my UiState(stateflow object) update after updating in the viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I update the uiState in the model by the `updateSelectedCategory(category = selectedCategory)` function, I checked through the logs int the viewmodel, everything is fine, it is updated. But, when I check this in the `WhehereToGoApp` compose function, the parameter `uiState.currentPlacesList` is not updated, why? I think I'm somehow not collecting the state correctly, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun WhereToGoApp() {
    val viewModel = WhereToGoViewModel()
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    val isCategoryScreen = (navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination?.route
        ?: WhereToGoAppScreens.Categories.name) == WhereToGoAppScreens.Categories.name

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            WhereToGoAppBar( // todo
                title = if (isCategoryScreen) {
                    "Select Category "
                } else {
                    uiState.value.selectedCategory.title
                },
                showNavigationIcon = !isCategoryScreen,
                onBackButtonClick = {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                }
            )
        }
    ) { contentPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = WhereToGoAppScreens.Categories.name
        ) {
            composable(route = WhereToGoAppScreens.Categories.name) {
                CategoriesScreen(
                    categoryList = LocalDataProvider.getCategories(),
                    onItemClick = { selectedCategory ->
                        viewModel.updateSelectedCategory(category = selectedCategory)
                        navController.navigate(WhereToGoAppScreens.Places.name)
                    },
                    paddingValues = contentPadding
                )
            }
            composable(route = WhereToGoAppScreens.Places.name) {
                PlacesScreen(
                    places = uiState.value.currentPlacesList,
                    onItemClick = { selectedPlace ->
                        viewModel.updateSelectedPlace(place = selectedPlace)
                        navController.navigate(WhereToGoAppScreens.PlaceDetails.name)
                    },
                    paddingValues = contentPadding
                )
            }
            composable(route = WhereToGoAppScreens.PlaceDetails.name) {
                PlaceDetailScreen(
                    place = uiState.value.selectedPlace,
                    paddingValues = contentPadding
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel code

```
class WhereToGoViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(WhereToGoUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<WhereToGoUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun updateSelectedCategory(category: Category) {
        _uiState.update { uiState ->
            uiState.copy(
                selectedCategory = category,
                currentPlacesList = LocalDataProvider.getPlaces().filter {
                    it.category == category
                }
            )
        }
    }

    fun updateSelectedPlace(place: Place) {
        _uiState.update {
            _uiState.value.copy(
                selectedPlace = place
            )
        }
    }

}

data class WhereToGoUiState(
    val selectedCategory: Category = Category.NightClub,
    val currentPlacesList: List<Place> = emptyList(),
    val selectedPlace: Place = LocalDataProvider.getPlaces()[0],
)
```

Comment: You are actually recreating viewModel every recomposition, it may be the reason your state remains with initial value after update

Comment: This was actually the cause of the problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you recreate the view model every time your screen recomposes.

```
val viewModel = WhereToGoViewModel()
```

After you update the state recomposition happens. So your `WhereToGoApp` gets, *roughly speaking*, executed again, it recreates the view model and fetches the state from there. Since the new instance of the view model does not know anything about previous state updates, it simply returns the initial value.

Comment: What should be done here then? Move the viewModel declaration to WhereToGoApp constructor?

Comment: @Mehmed depends on what you use for dependency injection

Comment: I use koinViewModel() as shown in its [docs](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose):
`ListScreen(val viewModel: ListViewModel = koinViewModel()) { ... }`